# looping a particular section of code (i have no idea what im doing)

Tags: imacros

I have followed too many people on Instagram up to the 7500 limit, I cant be bothered to unfollow every single one and not violate Instagram polices. I have recreated the code below with literally no knowledge of what I'm doing whatsoever. It randomly unfollows one account every 20-40 seconds which is brilliant, however again, to be sure i dont violate instagrams unfollow polices i want it to unfollow an account every 20-40 for 150 cycles, then wait for an hour, then continue and so on.

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 20); randomNumber;") 
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Following
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Unfollow
SET !LOOP -150
```

So what I'm looking for is something like this on the end I guess

```
WAIT SECONDS= 3600
LOOP 50
```

But again, I have no idea what I'm doing lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the extension, you can hit "Play Loop" on the main menu down near the bottom. You set how many times to loop under "Play macro repeatedly", just set the max to 50 and include `WAIT SECONDS=3600` at the bottom of your script